# Does an Android listener need to be running the whole time?

Tags: android, service

I'm writing my first independent Android app. It will sit in the background and respond to a few events generated by the OS, somewhere between a few times a day to a few times a week depending on the user.

Coming from a PC programming background, I thought I might need a service, but [Android Developers > Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) says:

> #### What is a Service?
>
> Most confusion about the Service class actually revolves around what it is *not*:
>
> - A Service is **not** a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.
> - A Service is **not** a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

The app should not need to consume any resources unless one of the events it's listening for happens. The user should also not need to actively use the app after it's been set up, only if they want to change its settings.

I have games that seem to do something similar to what I want. They sit in the background and can receive messages (e.g. it's now my turn), and when I click on the notification it loads the game into memory, which takes a few seconds longer than if it was already in memory.

If the user hasn't used the app's interface for a month, I want it to still be in operation (even if the device has been power-cycled) and respond to events but not to appear in the list of recent apps (assuming a month is long enough to push it off the end). Ideally, I want it to respond to the events within one second; it doesn't have to be near-instant. What's the normal way this is done?

1. An app (occasionally used) and a separate "service" process/thread (persistent)
2. A combined app and "service" (persistent)
3. A combined app and "service" (loaded into memory by events)

Comment: Notification seems only way to this when in background . In foreground you can go with Socket or Some persistent connection  You need to check [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) . Service can not run in background infinitely .

Comment: You can register event listener and in those event listeners you can start your services. no need for services to run in background alwasy

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment, but just to tell you that nothing prevent Android to kill your service, To restart your service after the user reboot its phone you can add a broadcast receiver and listen to  
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

.Also, if you don't want to display a notification while your service is running you will have to use a background service instead of foreground one. Hope this help.